# HP Compaq keyboard keys are messed up

Tags: keyboard, compaq-laptop

I have a HP Compaq notebook on which I have just installed Windows XP Ultimate, and I have a keyboard problem: The keys are inverted, for example if I press <kbd>M</kbd>, I get <kbd>0</kbd>.

I need to use the English keyboard.

Did anyone have the same problem? Can anyone help me?

Update: 
by inverted I mean messed up.

Comment: … Windows XP *Ultimate*? Also, which keys are not working, exactly? Are you sure you haven't enabled any Num-Pad functionality?

Comment: What @slhck - What on earth is XP Ultimate?!  Also, yes, this sounds *exactly like you have NumLock on*.  What specifically makes you say "inverted"?  That's oddly specific...please explain further.

Comment: Ultimate is a cracked version (yes, cracked). and yes, it seems that I have some Num-Pad functionality enabled because all the messed up keys, have numbers instead.

Comment: How does saying "they're messed up" help us in any way? **Which ones** are messed up **exactly**? And do you have NumPad on or not?

Comment: Finally solved! It was Fn + NumLock.

Comment: So...what you're saying is you did have NumLock on?  Good that it was simple, I suppose. :)

Comment: Yes, very, very simple if I had known that I should also press Fn key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check you don't have NumLock on.

Also, I highly advise you do not use a pirated version of Windows. You could leave yourself vulnerable to a lot of security and other problems... along with the fact it just isn't good (or legal).